# Is there a shorthand where One <or> More positionals match a Type in a multi signature

Tags: raku

I have this;

```
multi sub infix:<+> ( Measure:D $left, Measure:D $right ) is equiv( &infix:<+> ) is export { 
    my ( $result, $argument ) = inf-prep( $left, $right );
    return $result.add( $argument );
}
multi sub infix:<+> ( Measure:D $left, $right ) is equiv( &infix:<+> ) is export { 
    my ( $result, $argument ) = inf-prep( $left, $right );
    return $result.add( $argument );
}
multi sub infix:<+> ( $left, Measure:D $right ) is equiv( &infix:<+> ) is export { 
    my ( $result, $argument ) = inf-prep( $left, $right );
    return $result.add( $argument );
}
```

Is there a shorthand to avoid three multi sub declarations - the main aim here is to catch anything that has my custom Type i.e. Measure.

Comment: You can insert the actual code in only one of them and use [callsame](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/callsame) to call it. Other than ,that, I find it difficult to declare a signature in which one type depends on the other. Although you could also drop the Measure constraint, and call an exception if neither of them is a Measure.

Comment: @jjmerelo ah - callsame - excellent idea, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your signature you can use a single [Capture](https://docs.raku.org/type/Signature#Capture_parameters) for all parameters and constraint them with a `where` clause inspecting the capture for the desired number of positionals and if the Type is present.

For example the following sub expects two positionals where at least one is `Int:D:`

```
sub callWithInt(|c where { .elems == 2 && .list.any ~~ Int:D }) {
    # Just show the first Int:D received
    "called with {c.list.first(* ~~ Int)}".say
}
```

If you need to define different subs with the same signature, to avoid repeating the clause, create first a `subset` and use it as constraint:

```
subset hasInt of Capture where {
    .elems == 2 # Number of required positionals
    && .list.any ~~ Int:D # a Junction for the Type check
    # Avoid LTA error messages
    or fail('Need 2 positionals with an Int')
};

sub cwInts(hasInt |c) {
    "called with {c.list.first(* ~~ Int)}".say
}

sub adder(hasInt |c) { … }

cwInts(1, 'bar'); # "called with 1"
cwInts('foo', 3); # "called with 3"
cwInts('foo', 'barr') # Error! "I need 2 positionals with an Int"
cwInts(8); # Error!
```